# How to display Calendar logfile on Ventura?

Tags: calendar, ventura, logs

I currently encounter some difficulties with the use of CalDAV delegates on Calendar 11.0. I have activated debug mode and `CalDAV logging` but I can't find the logfile.

Comment: Debug menu can be found with `defaults write com.apple.iCal CDB 1`

Comment: @Thinkr I still have done this activation. But how can I show the logging?